# Android getAllCellInfo() returns wrong LAC

Tags: android, cellinfo

in my Android App I will receive all the CI, MNC, MCC and LAC of each Base Station next to the device. Therefore I use `getAllCellInfo()`.

```
var cellInfoList = telephonyManager.allCellInfo
```

In the response I get for my serving cell all required information correctly. For the neighboring cells I receive a correct CI, MNC and MCC. The Location Area Code is incorrect, because it`s the same as the CI. Is there any workaround to get the correct LAC?

Used different devices, Samsung, Huawai, Xiaomi.
With a Samsung device I was not able to receive any data of the neighboring cells. With Huawai and Xiaomi the LAC was incorrect.